# Micro/nano skin implants to signal hole cards at the WSOP?

Tags: texas-hold-em, live, wsop, cheating

Given that it is possible to send remote electric shocks, skin itches and muscle twitches to specific areas of the body using nano/micro-implants, is it possible to rig the WSOP which uses cameras and broadcasts hole cards live?

Comment: How would *you* do it? I'd be interested to see your personal answer.

Comment: Really, they broadcast the hole cards live?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting thought, I think it is possible but it would be very difficult to pull off depending on the method used.

- I believe the WSOP now uses RFID cards instead of hole cams to show the player cards on the live broadcast. Using a nano/micro-implant, one could imagine that a player could get information about other players cards. This is impossible at the moment because RFID is not a very long range signal, so the player would have to get very close to an opponents cards to read them (assuming this player can read the card's RFID signal with an implanted micro chip, a big challenge in itself.)
- As far as cheating by watching the live broadcast goes, there is usually around a half hour delay between the actual tournament and the live broadcast. I watched the 2018 $100k PCA Super High Roller (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHVHqc9rrF0) and players at the table actually had their phones out and were watching the live broadcast as it was happening. This was not the WSOP but I imagine that they have a similar delay set up.

I do not think it is impossible to cheat with all of the signals that are being sent due to the live broadcast. It would be very difficult to do so because a player is not able to tamper with any broadcasting equipment, and a player obviously can not be seen receiving any information.